# 3dfx driver for modern graphic cards?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, opengl

I have some older Windows games that were optimized for 3dfx Glide.

I just wonder if there is a driver that can fake Glide on a modern system, so that I can use the 3dfx version of those games?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a Glide "Wrapper" Use at your own risk.

http://www.sierrahelp.com/Utilities/DisplayUtilities/GlideWrappers.html

https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=glide+wrapper&aq=f&aqi=g9g-m1&aql=&oq=